# from appname.models import Publisher, Author, Book

Tags: django, django-models, pythonpath

Very new to Django so please bear with me. Following along with the Django polls project using The Django Book's classes (Publisher, Author, Book). I've been stuck on importing my models in the shell.

The app name is General and the project name is mysite

The error:

```
>>> from General.models import Publisher, Author, Book

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
from General.models import Publisher, Author, Book
ImportError: No module named General.models
>>>
```

My folders:

```
C:\
BookShelf/
  sqlite3.db
  mysite/
    mysite
    media
    manage.py
    General/
       _init_.py
       _init_.pyc
       models.py
       models.pyc
       tests.py
       views.py
```

if this helps:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C
:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\BookShelf\\mysite\\General\\models.py', 'C:\\WIN
DOWS\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\"C:\\BookShelf\\mysite\\General\\m
odels.py"', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\s
ite-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']  
>>>
```

I've tried 'from mysite.General.models' with no success as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

`C:\BookShelf\mysite` should be in your `PYTHONPATH`. Try following -

```
cd C:\BookShelf\mysite
python manage.py shell
from General.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

You should always use `python manage.py shell` to open a python shell for django projects. `manage.py` puts your project’s package on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_init_.py` files should be named `__init__.py` - two underscores each side.

Note that it's probably not good practice to call your app `General` - you should use all lower case names for packages.

Comment: Changed to general. Thanks